# Handling object being updated/deleted in database but not in linq cache

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, datacontext

I have an extremely convoluted issue with a system where many stored procs will be run when the user submits a page with asp webforms. It will either update or delete certain items from the relevant tables but as this all happens in stored procedures linq to sql has no knowledge of this logic, so its caches still sit there with the deleted items in its cache.

The issue I am seeing is down to a composite key based table being updated, so all the contents are deleted via a stored procedure, then items are re-created and inserted with new values, however if you assume the entity looks like:

```
public class SomeCompositeEntity
{
    public long UserId {get;set;}
    public smallint ActionTypeId {get;set;}
    public int ActionValue {get;set;}
}
```

So in this case if I had 10 of them, and updated 3, all of them would be deleted via this stored procedure, then would be recreated, 7 of them being identical to the existing ones and 3 being same Ids but different values.

The problem is though as the delete only happens in the DB space, linq is not aware of this, so when you try to save these entities which linq to sql still has it blows up with DuplicateKeyException, which it is correct to do.

So if I were to catch the DuplicateKeyException then take the entity and tell linq to sql to refresh it overwriting changes from the DB, would it remove the object from the cache if it has been deleted? as the documentation is not clear on that?

I would love to remove the stored procedure and a lot of the other convoluted process but the client is adamant that it cannot be changed incase it somehow triggers the end of days... so given the position I am in here if there are any other ideas on how to handle this scenario then it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I am having to do a nasty thing... and empty Linq's cache before each save. I tried to be reactive to the exception and handle it, but I cannot update the object as its within a changed state, so then tried to be pro active and stop the exception happening but this required me to check if items were in the cache, and if so remove them or swap/merge them, and the errors still came in.

So anyway here is the code I ended up using which is horrible but does the job, as I will also be moving to short life connections when I implement Ninject (with request based scope) then hopefully this will become even less of an issue.

```
public static void ClearEntityCache(this IDataContext dataContext)
        {
            const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var method = dataContext.GetType().GetMethod("ClearCache", flags);
            method.Invoke(dataContext, null);
        }
```

The IDataContext above is a simple wrapper interface I made for mocking data layers for unit testing.